# New to C++, I'm not sure what I did wrong

Tags: c++

I''m kind of new to this, but I'm trying to run a hello world program in Eclipse Mars and I just keep getting errors. Can anyone give me a hand?

[image]

Comment: You're missing a semicolon, hover over the error, it should tell you something like that. Please include only the text of the code in the future. Images don't last forever.

Comment: The image in the link is now missing. Can you please copy your source code to your question next time? The question editor allows you to insert and format your source code very well.

Answer (score 0):

You need put a semicolon after every line, like this:

return 0;

Answer (score 0):

every statement must end with a semicolon and you are missing that in the return...

do this:

```
return 0;
```